# Showing that $m(E_1\times E_2)=m(E_1)m(E_2)$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

[image]

> Please find the sentence underlined with red. Can anyone tell me how to use the corollary to attain the result? Is
>   $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d_2}} m((E_1\times E_2)^y)\mathrm{d}y$$
>   helpful? I'm stuck with this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Hints: Can you see that $E^y = E_1$ and that $m(E_2) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d_2}} dy$?

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $E=E_1\times E_2$ is measurable, by Corollary 3.3, we have
\begin{align*}
m(E)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d_2}} m(E^y)dy =\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d_2}} m(E_1)\chi_{E_2}dy=m(E_1)\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d_2}}\chi_{E_2}dy=m(E_1)m(E_2)
\end{align*}

because
$$E^y=\begin{cases}
E_1&,y\in E_2 \\
\emptyset&,y\notin E_2.
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you. But that $E^y=E_1$ depends on whether $y$ lies in $E_2$. I don't think we can make such an assertion. Also, could you explain why $m(E_2) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d_2}} dy$? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Steve  I think I made a mistake. I edited the answer. Let me know if anything is not clear.